# Vision product search indexing time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-product-search

I have a question regarding Google Vision product search.
To test API I uploaded 700 products and 700 images from Kaggle dataset: 300x800px each.
API listProductSets gives that indexing took some time, and each hour its increasing, as you can notice in the following error messages:

> Product set [[{".../testProductSet","displayName":"Test product
>   set","indexTime":{"seconds":"1578776083","nanos":909481355},"indexError":{"details":[],"code":0,"message":""}}],null,null]
>
> Product set [[{"name":"...testProductSet","displayName":"Test product
>   set","indexTime":{"seconds":"1578779673","nanos":63308579},"indexError":{"details":[],"code":0,"message":""}}],null,null]

Does it means that indexing will take some more time or its indicates that there is an error in API?

Indexing is going for 2 days in a row, still no images indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index time indicates the time at which it was last indexed. If the time keeps increasing, that means it is still up to date.

What did you do to check if the images were indexed?

Comment: Thanks to point me out. Yes, index was performed by service. I made wrong request to listReferenceImages api method and got empty results.